# Hide Settings Bundle in Settings.app

Tags: iphone, inappsettingskit

I have created an iOS 4.0 app with a Settings bundle. I am using the InAppSettingsKit (http://www.inappsettingskit.com) which presents the settings in the app. This allows the user to modify those settings directly from within the app, without the need to go to the external iPhone Settings.app. As the settings are accessible from inside the app (and I am doing some custom styling to the in-app settings screen) I would like to stop the Settings bundle from appearing in the iPhone Settings.app. Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

InAppSettingKit allows the use of an internal only settings bundle.  Rename Settings.bundle to be this and then the OS wont find it to put it in the Main Settings part

Check out "[Some little extras](http://inappsettingskit.com/)" on the product page